# "Partly" reducing a Stream

Tags: java, java-stream, reduce

Given the following context:

```
public interface IAdditive<T> {
    /** True if still capable to crunch. */
    boolean canCrunch();
    /** True if capable to crunch with B. */
    boolean canCrunch(T other);
    /** Returns a new T which is the sum of this and other */
    T crunch(T other);    
}
```

```
class A implements IAdditive<A> {
    ..
    A crunch(A other) {...}
}
```

```
class B extends A {
    ...
    B crunch(B other) {...}
}
```

```
class C implements IAdditive<C> {
    ...
    C crunch(C other) {...}
}
```

Now I want to "crunch" a Stream of Implementations

```
/** Chrunches the streams where possible */
public Stream<A> crunchStream(Stream s) {
    return s.map(...);
}
```

I am stuck with my rather naive approach:

```
public Set<A> collect(Stream<A> stream) {
    Set<I> res = new HashSet<>();
    Set<I> set = stream
            .filter(IAdditive::canCrunch)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    set.forEach(setItem -> set.stream()
            .filter(concurrentItem -> concurrentItem.canCrunch(setItem))
            .map(setItem::crunch)
            .forEach(res::add));
    return res;
}
```

That should be flawed. I am unfolding the stream, add mandatory complexity,  and If I want the interface to offer that in a default method I would have to use rawtypes.

I believe I could use some help :-)

Comment: what is `I` in your `collect` method? Is that a use of generic or you typed the name of an interface/class incorrectly?

Comment: Im ment that as an Implementation. Should have used 'A'

Comment: You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63082621/edit) in that case to update the code accordingly.

Comment: Also, are you looking for something like `public Set<A> collect(Stream<A> stream) {
        return stream
                .filter(A::canCrunch)
                .map(a -> a.crunch(a))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }`?

Comment: Not exactly. Think of shop items. Identical products can "melt" into a single identity-product with a highter amount-property, limited to its box size.

`a.canCrunch` accounts for the general capacity to be part of a crunch (and is cheaper to call). `a.canCrunch(a2)` checks if those two candidates are actually valid to pair.

Comment: So, given a `Stream<S>`, which may contain `A`s, `B`s and `C`s, you want a `Map<Class<? extends IAdditive>, IAdditive>`, containing only one A, one B and one C, each "crushed"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think this is what you want:

```
public static interface Additive<T> {
    default public Additive<T> crunch(Additive<T> other) { return null; }
}

public static class A implements Additive<A> {};

public static class B implements Additive<B> {};

public static class C implements Additive<C> {};

/**
 * Takes a stream of arbitrary Additives and returns a Set containing
 * only one crunched Additive for each type
 * 
 * @param stream additives to crunch
 * @return crunched set
 */
public Set<Additive<?>> crunch(Stream<Additive<?>> stream) {
    return stream
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getClass()))
        .values().stream()
        .map(values -> values.stream().reduce(Additive::crunch).get())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

/**
 * Takes a stream of arbitrary Additives and returns a Set containing
 * only one crunched Additive for each type
 * 
 * @param stream additives to crunch
 * @return crunched set
 */
public Collection<Additive<Object>> crunchMap(Stream<Additive<?>> stream) {
    return stream
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getClass(), v -> (Additive<Object>) v, (a, b) -> a.crunch(b))).values();
}
```

Both method should produce the desired output. They take a Stream containing arbitrary `Additive`s, group them by actual type, then crunch the ones of the same type into only one object, and finally return a `Set` or `Collection` containing only one object for each type of `Additive`.

I have laid out two different approaches. The first approach first groups into a map, and then crunches all similar types. this is perhaps the easier to understand method.

the second approach uses a mapping collector, mapping each additive to its class as key, and doing a no-op for the value, then, on a key collision, crunches the new value with the old values and puts that into the map. its a bit more involved, a bit harder to read and needs a bit more generic-fu to actually get to work.

Note that passing a Stream as parameter doesn't have any benefit - just pass the collection. In fact, passing streams is discouraged as you can never be sure who has already operated on the stream and who hasn't, leading to exceptions when the stream is already closed.

Note that I do not use your `canCrunch` method, but rely on the fact that each type can crunch itself and only itself, but no less. This is far easier to enforce and deal with than objects of same types not being able to be crushed. if you want that, you need some form to distinguish them and to change the classificator accordingly.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you. I've never seen the `.groupBy` method. I'll definitely think about it more now.